# extend internal precision in rapidminer 5.3

Tags: import, precision, rapidminer

im currently troubled with the float precision in rapidminer 5.3. I'm loading some float from a csv which look like this: 1.234567E10. my problem is any number with an exponent smaller than -9 is just imported as 0, numbers with greater exponents are correctly imported as e.g. 8.000562E-3 -> 0.008000562. [Edit: i'm using the "Read CSV" function]
do i need to increase the internal precision of rapidminer and how do i do this?
I already increased the display of rapidminer.general.fractiondigits.numbers which gives me a lot if trailing zeros e.g. 8.000562E-3 -> 0.008000562000000000 but still if the exponent is -9 or smaller it will only show 8.000562E-9 -> 0.
thanks for any help =).
EDIT: i checked "read CSV", the numbers should be imported as "double_array". the machiene epsilon for double is about 1E-16. the behaviour i encounter looks like its treated as a single precision, which has an eps about 1E-9.Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with version 7.4 and imports work correctly so this looks like a fix has been made.

Why not simply use the latest version?